# Xcode Log not showing the crash or exceptions due to Testflight

Tags: ios, ios5, testflight

I am using Xcode 4.2 and recently integrated the test flight sdk due to test flight Xcode now not printing the crash and exception in log...

Comment: Have you got the log?? I cannot see it either..